Why would assigning a dummy WebViewClient alter the behavior of the Android WebView?
I have an Android Application that is nothing but an empty activity with the following WebView initialization on it, displaying a SharePoint page.
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
setContentView(webView);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // <---- this line breaks the login

webView.loadUrl("https://eponalabs.sharepoint.com");

I was under the impression that the default implementation of the WebViewClient would not alter the behavior, but simply setting it breaks the SharePoint login process.

What is the difference between this WebViewClient and the stock WebView behavior, and how do I get it to work the same? I need the WebViewClient's methods to implement custom resource loading and analysis.
